# Office 365 Authentication: Use the authorization code to request an access token

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory

I am working through this document [Authorize access to web applications using OAuth 2.0 and Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) and have got to the point where I receive the intialial authorisation code when signing in successfully but I having difficulty getting the authorisation token. As I understand it I need to send the code in a POST to get the token.

The POST request I have is:

```
$code_received = $_GET['code']; //I get a code successfully

$url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com';

$body="grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=myappid&code=" . $code_received . "&redirect_uri=https://mysite/auth.php&client_secret=***";

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'content' => $body
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
var_dump($result);
```

The result I get is bool(false) .... so nothing returned - neither a token or an error. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you looking to parse the ADFS response yourself? Having worked through a lot of issues recently, I turned to this (https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml) which came in handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify the `resource` at least in `$body`. That should be the resource URI for the API you are trying to use. It tells Azure AD what API you want to call.

For Microsoft Graph API that is `https://graph.microsoft.com`.

For Azure AD Graph API it is `https://graph.windows.net`.